# Compare two arrays and count incidents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two array

```
$array1=('18753933','18753933','18771982')
$array2=('18753933','18771982')
```

I'm going through each one to compare the values that are the same in each array

```
var contarArticulosCargados=0;

for(var $i=0;$i<$array1.length;$i++) {
    for(var $j=0;$j<$array2.length;$j++) {
        if($array1[$i]===$array[$j]) {
            countArticulosCargados++;
        }
    }
}

console.log(countArticlesLoaded);
```

This example that I have put in my code works well, that is to say, I am doing the comparison and it works without problem.

What do I want to do? (It's what I have no idea how to do)

As you can see in `$array1` is the value 18753933 and in `$array2` is also the value `18753933`.

What I want is that when the value is repeated this is counted, in the `$array1` the value `18753933` is `2` times and the value `18771982` is `1` time.

I want to see something like this:

```
18753933 repeats: 2 
18771982 is repeated: 1
```

could you give me an idea of what I'm missing? I always find it hard to make comparisons between arrays. Thank you.

Comment: `('18753933','18753933','18771982')` is not an array. It should be wrapped inside `[]`

Comment: If you are right, I miss the brackets, but it is a hypothetical example, the idea is what I ask, how can I count the values that are repeated and keep the separate count?

Answer (score 2):

Simply map over array2 and take the length of the filtered array1.

```js
const a1 = ['18753933','18753933','18771982'];
const a2 = ['18753933','18771982'];

const res = a2.map(e => ({[e]: a1.filter(k => k === e).length}));
console.log(res);
```

To remove elements that were not found, you could filter first

```
a2.filter(e => a1.includes(e)).map(e => ({[e]: a1.filter(k => k === e).length}))
```

or after

```
a2.map(e => ({[e]: a1.filter(k => k === e).length})).filter(e => Object.values(e).every(x => x > 0));
```

Or use reduce

```js
const a1 = ['18753933','18753933','18771982'];
const a2 = ['18753933','18771982'];

const res = a2.reduce((a, b) => {
  const l = a1.filter(e => e === b).length;
  if (l) a[b] = l;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Pretty nice solution +1. I think you should add a way with simple loops as the OP seems beginner.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a1 = ['18753933','18753933','18771982'];
const a2 = ['18753933','18771982'];

const r = {};

a2.forEach(_ => r[_] = 0)

a1.forEach(_ => {
    if (r[_] === 0 || r[_]) {
        r[_] += 1
    }
})

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like you'll need to do is create an Array of Objects. Something like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>JavaScript Array of Objects</h2>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    var array1 = ['18753933', '18753933', '18771982'];
    var array2 = ['18753933', '18771982'];
    var contarArticulosCargados = [];

    // for each of the numbers in array2
    for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {

      // create an object
      contarArticulosCargados.push({
        articulos: array2[i],
        contar: 0
      });

      // for each of the numbers in array2
      for (var j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {

        if (array2[i] === array1[j]) {
          // increment counter for the object
          var foo = contarArticulosCargados.length - 1;
          contarArticulosCargados[foo].contar++;

        }
      }
    }

    // create string for result
    var result = "";
    for (var k = 0; k < contarArticulosCargados.length; k++) {
      result += contarArticulosCargados[k].articulos + " repeats: " + contarArticulosCargados[k].contar + ". ";
    }

    // send result to html
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
    // or console as string
    console.log(result);
    // or console as array
    console.log(contarArticulosCargados);

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

You can copy & paste the html to test, to see the results.

You might want to switch array1 & array2, but I think I have them the right way around (from your example).

Change array1 to something else might help visualisation

```
var array1 = ['18753933', '18753933', '18771982', '18771982', '18771982', '18771982', '18771982', '18771982', '18771982'];
```

If array1 was as above, the output is:

```
18753933 repeats: 2. 18771982 repeats: 7.
```

Or if array1 is as originally stated in the question, the output is:

```
18753933 repeats: 2. 18771982 repeats: 1.
```

But, of course the question tags are `JavaScript` & `jQuery` but the code is 
`PHP`. So I'm wrong either way.